# Outlook C# - Processing MailItem and MeetingItem in same function?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, email, outlook

I have written some C# code that reads emails from Microsoft Outlook and writes the emails into a MongoDB. Specifically, my code puts an email into a MongoDB-compatible [BsonDocument](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.9/reference/bson/bson_document/), and then it inserts the BsonDocument into a MongoDB collection.

In the C# interface to Outlook, you can open a [`Folder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.folder?view=outlook-pia) and call [`Folder.Items`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mapifolder.items?view=outlook-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Outlook_MAPIFolder_Items). This returns an object of type `Items`. When you iterate over an `Items` object, you encounter multiple object types, including [`MailItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.mailitem?view=outlook-pia) and [`MeetingItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.meetingitem?view=outlook-pia). Most of the fields in MailItem and MeetingItem are the same (e.g. `Body`, `Subject`, etc). In my code example below, I have separate functions to process MailItem and MeetingItem. However, this leads to code duplication.

**So, my question is: is it there a way to write a function that is agnostic to whether the input is of type `MailItem` or `MeetingItem`?**

#### Minimal code example

---

In my program, I import these things:

```
using Bson = MongoDB.Bson;
using Driver = MongoDB.Driver;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
```

And, the next three snippets comprise the body of the program:

```
namespace ReadEmail{
    class Program{
        public static Bson.BsonDocument convertMailItemToBson(Outlook.MailItem item){
            Bson.BsonDocument retval = new Bson.BsonDocument();
            retval.Add("Body", item.Body);
            retval.Add("Subject", item.Subject);
            return retval;
     }
```

...and the same code a second time for MeetingItem:

```
        public static Bson.BsonDocument convertMeetingItemToBson(Outlook.MeetingItem item){
            Bson.BsonDocument retval = new Bson.BsonDocument();
            retval.Add("Body", item.Body);
            retval.Add("Subject", item.Subject);
            return retval;
        }
```

Finally, a main function to connect to Outlook, connect to MongoDB, and feed emails and meetings into the above functions:

```
        static void Main(string[] args){
            Outlook.Application outlookApplication = new Outlook.Application();
            Outlook.NameSpace outlookNamespace = outlookApplication.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = outlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            var dbClient = new Driver.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost");
            var database = dbClient.GetDatabase("myDb");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<Bson.BsonDocument>("myCollection1");

            Outlook.Items items = folder.Items;
            foreach (var item in items){
                if (item is Outlook.MailItem mailItem){
                    Bson.BsonDocument iBson = convertMailItemToBson(mailItem);
                    collection.InsertOne(iBson);
                }
                else if (item is Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem){
                    Bson.BsonDocument iBson = convertMeetingItemToBson(meetingItem);
                    collection.InsertOne(iBson);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The full program for the above code is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/forresti/c55fb76772659679d75c834d59dc72ea). Note that in the full program, we aren't just reading 2 fields (Subject and Body). Instead, in the full program, we are reading 25 fields.

#### One thing I tried that hasn't yet worked

---

For our purposes, the only difference between MailItem and MeetingItem that matters is that MeetingItem doesn't have the To, CC, or BCC fields. So, I thought I could create a templatized function as follows:

```
        public static Bson.BsonDocument convertItemToBson<T>(T item) where T : Outlook.MailItem, Outlook.MeetingItem
        {
            Bson.BsonDocument retval = new Bson.BsonDocument();
            retval.Add("Body", item.Body);
            retval.Add("Subject", item.Subject);
            return retval;
        }
```

However, I get the following compiler error:
[CS0229 Ambiguity between '_MailItem.Body' and '_MeetingItem.Body'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0229).

Note that out of the 25 fields in the [full program](https://gist.github.com/forresti/c55fb76772659679d75c834d59dc72ea), all of them have this error. Also note that for my full templatized version, I removed the usage of the To, CC, and BCC fields, because these fields exist in MailItem but not MeetingItem.

#### Recap

---

To summarize the question: In the above code, is there a way to combine `convertMailItemToBson()` and `convertMeetingItemToBson()` into one function that can accept either a `MailItem` or a `MeetingItem` as input?

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the parameters in method.

```
public static Bson.BsonDocument convertItemToBson(string body, string subject){
        Bson.BsonDocument retval = new Bson.BsonDocument();
        retval.Add("Body", body);
        retval.Add("Subject", subject);
        return retval;
    }
```

and while calling you can call like below.

```
foreach (var item in items){
            if (item is Outlook.MailItem mItem){
                Bson.BsonDocument iBson = convertItemToBson(mItem.Body, mItem.Subject);
                collection.InsertOne(iBson);
            }
else if(item is Outlook.MailItem mItem){
Bson.BsonDocument iBson = convertItemToBson(mItem.Body, mItem.Subject);
                collection.InsertOne(iBson);
}
```

}

There could be many possibilities. I think this would work. I have not tested the code as i don't have all code. Feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I forgot to mention: instead of taking 2 fields from the MailItem or MeetingItem, in my real application I am actually extracting about 25 fields. And, I sometimes add code to extract more fields too. Some fields need special processing too. So, that would be a really long function signature!

Comment: Can you provide your code? It is hard to visualize dependencies between object and find relationship to remove duplication.

Comment: Here is the code: https://gist.github.com/forresti/c55fb76772659679d75c834d59dc72ea

Comment: You could create an interface which implement Outlook.MeetingItem and Outlook.MailItem and while iterating cast it into that interface like Interface A:MeetingItem,MailItem. Then merge two methods and check if property exist on type or not.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the item as a generic `object` and use reflection to read the property values.